# Pinescript set a position with my whole equity

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

*Hello there,*
I am trying to test my strategy with a pinescript and would need some help please.

### Strategy

If the price of the S&P500 is obove the 200-days-moving-average i'm in the market with all my capital. If it drops below, i'm selling everything. No short position. That's it, quite simple. But i don't get it how i can set the position size to my current equity.

### Script-Code

```
// S&P 500 Strategie Test
strategy("S&P500 3x", initial_capital=10000)

// 200-day-moving-average
ema200 = sma(close, 200)

// conditions
long = close > ema200
short = close < ema200

positionSize = abs(strategy.equity)

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=postionSize, when = long)
strategy.close("Long", when = short)
```

### Error

```
Script could not be translated from: |B|var initialCapital = strategy.equity|E|
|EMPTY_V1|
```

### Leverage

In a next step, i want to see what happens if i leverage my position.
To do this i want to multiply the profit/loss of each trade with a factor of let's say 3. Anyone got an idea how to set this up? Maybe save the profit/loss, multiply it and then add it to the total equity, if such a thing is possible. Simply multiplying the initial capital by 3 doesn't work for me.

---

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set default order size as 100% from equity in function `strategy()` (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy) with `default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity` ([https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy{dot}percent_of_equity](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dpercent_of_equity)) and `default_qty_value = 100`

Comment: Thank you a lot!! :)